# Thymeleaf setting object attribute based on click

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

What I am trying to do set object user variable attribute based on click.

`

```
 <form class="container" th:action="@{/processSignup}" method="post" 
   th:object="${user}">

    <div class="switch">
        <div class="MenteeSignUp" onclick="tab1();" th:onclick="*{}"  >Mentee</div>
        <div class="MentorSignUp" onclick="tab2();" th:value="MENTOR" th:field="*{userRole}">Mentor</div>
    </div>
```

`

Trying to add different role-based what user click which either mentor or mentee which you can see from the screenshot.

I am kind of new to thyme leaf, so I tried to have th:onClick and then tried to assign it but it didn't work

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfJDd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have there doesn't really make sense. `<div />`s do not have a `value` attribute, and the expression in a `th:onclick` must be valid javascript (instead you have a blank selection variable expressions: `th:onclick="*{}"`).  Maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
<form class="container" th:action="@{/processSignup}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{userRole}" id="userRole" />
    
    <div class="switch">
        <div class="MenteeSignUp" onclick="document.getElementById('userRole').value = 'MENTEE';">Mentee</div>
        <div class="MentorSignUp" onclick="document.getElementById('userRole').value = 'MENTOR';">Mentor</div>
    </div>
```